# transform in function javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello and I could do with this one function?
I am new to `javascript`.

I need to encapsulate the code below in a function like:

```
ConfirmDelete function () {

};
```

that does the same as this:

```
$('.btn-danger').on('click', function (e, confirmed) {
    if (!confirmed) {
        e.preventDefault();
        bootbox.confirm("Are you sure?", function (response) {
            if (response) {
                $('.btn-danger').trigger('click', true);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Does 'confirmed' value depend on user input?

Comment: no, my code in form is one button <button type="submit" onclick="ConfirmDelete() "class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Eliminar"><span class="delete"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i></span> </button>

Comment: You should always handle form submit via the `submit` event, on the `form` element, as `click` will not fire if you use the keyboard to submit a form (e.g. via enter on a field).

Comment: An idea could be instead of triggering again a 'click' you could get the reference to the form `form = $('.btn-danger').closest('form')` and on that element trigger the submit event

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been over your code and the jQuery version is your best bet. You can't get the same functionality from inline handlers connected to the button.

You will want to move to the `submit` event of the `form` as click on a single button is unreliable (e.g. when using keyboard). e.g. You would want to change it to something like:

```
$('form:has(.btn-danger)').on('submit', function (e, confirmed) {
    var $form = $(this);
    if (!confirmed) {
        e.preventDefault();
        bootbox.confirm("Are you sure?", function (response) {
            if (response) {
                $form.trigger('submit', true);
            }
        });
    }
});
```